# VBA code to copy entire columns by searching selected multiple headers

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find a loop (sorry, don't know the correct word to use here) that'll help me to select the entire column and copy that content on another location - Maybe (Sheet2.A1) cell

I've the code for finding the "Address1" Header and get the columns of that header. But I've a list of headers now, that need to be searched on the header row and get their entire columns copied to another location.

The header I'm searching would be like Address1, Address3, Address5 (random). I'd be able to place these headers on another sheet so the vba code can pick it from there for the search (sheet 3)

The code I have as below that'll search and give me only "Address1"

```
Sub FindAddressColumn()
Dim rngAddress As Range
Set rngAddress = Range("A1:Z1").Find("Address1")
 If rngAddress Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "Address column was not found."
  Exit Sub
 End If
Range(rngAddress, rngAddress.End(xlDown)).Select
End Sub
```

Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated. I was able to find the information of copying only a single column, but now have the challenge of multiple headers which need to be copied. Please help friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a sample....

```
Sub FindAddressColumn()
Dim rngAddress As Range, a As String

For Each a In Array("Address1", "Address2", "Address3", "Address4")
    Set rngAddress = Nothing
    Set rngAddress = Range("A1:Z1").Find(a)
    If Not rngAddress Is Nothing Then
        'Your Task goes here...
        Range(rngAddress, rngAddress.End(xlDown)).Select
    End If
Next a

End Sub
```